# How to pan an image? (Having trouble setting up projection matrix correctly)

Tags: c#, math, opengl

I'm making a little WinForms app where you can open a photo, pan around, and zoom in.

[image]

Having a little trouble figuring out the logic to pan it. When I middle click and drag around, it should pan the image, but it's resizing (stretching) and moving it.

I figured I could do the panning simply by adjusting the projection matrix via `glOrtho`. Here's the code, perhaps someone can point me in the right direction:

```
private void glControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        _mousePos = e.Location;
    }
}

private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Middle))
    {
        int dx = e.X - _mousePos.X;
        int dy = e.Y - _mousePos.Y;
        _viewRect.X += dx;
        _viewRect.Y += dy;
        UpdateView();
        _mousePos = e.Location;
    }
}

void UpdateView()
{
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Ortho(_viewRect.X, _viewRect.Width, _viewRect.Height, _viewRect.Y, -1, 1);
    glControl1.Invalidate();
    this.Text = string.Format("{0},{1} {2}x{3}", _viewRect.X, _viewRect.Y, _viewRect.Width, _viewRect.Height);
}
```

The viewport is initially set to the full size of the gl control:

```
int w = glControl1.Width;
int h = glControl1.Height;

GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h);
```

Image is rendered like this:

```
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
{
    GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
    GL.TexCoord2(0, 1); GL.Vertex2(0, _texture.Height);
    GL.TexCoord2(1, 1); GL.Vertex2(_texture.Width, _texture.Height);
    GL.TexCoord2(1, 0); GL.Vertex2(_texture.Width, 0);
}
```

In the screenshot, the titlebar shows x and y coordinates -146,-140. Since I'm drawing the image at 0,0, I would expect the top left pixel of the gl control to be 146,140 in image coordinates. Clearly my conceptual model is wrong.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using a `PictureBox` and change its coordinates to move the image around?

Comment: @GETah: Yes. I plan on doing more with this GLControl; going to be drawing other things on it, and I want nice smooth GPU-accelerated transitions.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you thought about WPF instead?

Comment: @GETah: I'd like to use WPF, but the GLControl doesn't work nicely with it, and that doesn't really help me either. This is an OpenGL issue, not to do with the windows GUI.

Comment: My point was, are there showstoppers for using WPF as your rendering platform? It is definitely better than WinForms (less performance than OpenGL of course)

Comment: @GETah: Yes. I quite like OpenGL, and I'm already familiar with it. This is just a small app, I don't feel like getting all intimate with WPF and learning how to draw and rotate and do smooth transitions. And I hate XAML.

Comment: Oh I see. These geometrical operations are really all simplified in WPF

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. `glOrtho` uses `right` and `bottom` not `width` and `height`.

Updated my function:

```
private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Middle))
    {
        int dx = e.X - _mousePos.X;
        int dy = e.Y - _mousePos.Y;
        _viewRect.X -= dx * (_viewRect.Width / glControl1.Width);
        _viewRect.Y -= dy * (_viewRect.Height / glControl1.Height);
        _mousePos = e.Location;
        UpdateView();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Update to fix screen- to view- coordinates problem.

Comment: Still a problem, after you've zoomed in (or out), it doesn't pan as you'd expect. If move your cursor 10 pixels, it pans 10 pixels in view coordinates, not screen coordinates.